# Bionic Beaver settings menu items missing

Tags: display, power-management, settings

Can you tell me where my power, display and other buttons are?

[image]

Ubuntu 18.04, gnome-control-center is installed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What has happened is that you have entered the "Details" section of Gnome Control Center. Since, Gnome Control Center now remembers where you last were, you're seeing this section every time you open it directly.

[image: screenshot of the comment by pomsky referencing Gnome Control Center remembering its last state]

To get out of this section, simply click the "<" button next to details, and it will take you back to the list of configuration panels.